# Find a all the words that do not contain the letters a,c,h,k and A,C,H,K with regex and grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to find all the word not containing specific characters.
What I have so far:

```
^[^achk]+$|^[^ACHK]+$
```

- ^ - start of a string
- [^achk] - not a,c,h,k
- + - one or more
- $ -   end of string

This does not work. Am I using the "or" expression right?

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: it's not working because the word `"ACHK"` matches `^[^achk]+$` (and visa versa)

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want: `^[^achkACHK]+$`

Comment: this will just find any character that does not match the specified.. he's looking for whole words

Comment: @ilia: My bad. Corrected.